# How can I summon a meteorite?

Tags: terraria

I've heard people talk (or at least, saw them write on forums) that they summoned meteors to create meteorite weapons and armor.

How do I exactly spawn these meteors and what can I make out of meteor?

Comment: Nice try, Sephiroth!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meteors can fall naturally (but fairly rarely) in game, but can also be summoned by breaking shadow orbs.  These orbs, which are purple looking and float around can be found at the bottom of chasms in areas of corruption, and can be broken with hammer type weapons, or dynamite.  For more info, see this wiki page: [Shadow Orb](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shadow_orb)

As for what can be made, this is from the wiki:  http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteorite_Bar

> Meteorite bars are made from six
>   meteorite ores. Meteor bars can be
>   used to create the much coveted
>   [Hamaxes](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hamaxe), [Space Guns](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Space_Gun), [Star
>   Cannons](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Star_Cannon) and [Phaseblades](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Phaseblade). They
>   are also used for making [meteor
>   shot](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteor_Shot) which is ammo like musket
>   balls but stronger, and [Meteorite
>   Armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteorite_Armor).

Comment: Am I correct that if you break shadow orbs It's also possible that the eye of cthulu or the eater of worlds can spawn?

Comment: @Sir Ksilem — The Eater spawns every third orb.  It's believed that the Eye can spawn randomly any time an orb is broken, but it hasn't been rigorously tested and the devs aren't saying.  Check out the [official wiki](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Shadow_Orb) for details.

Comment: Wow, good to know. I have never had an eye spawn due to an orb.. Maybe its because I generally break them during the day?